# "Can I have" vs "Can I am have"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, difference

Which is better or right? or all my sentences are incorrect?

> Can I have that?

or

> Can I am have that?

Comment: #1 is correct, #2 isn't. '*Can*' works as a modal verb here, while the verb is *have*. You can't and have no reason to add another verb (*am*) here.

Comment: Thans for explanation!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic format for asking a question is like this:

*"Wh"(words)  + Auxiliary verb + subject + verb + object + ?*

or

*Auxiliary verb + subject + verb + object + ?*

So according to this formula, your first statement is correct, whereas in your second statement you have incorrectly included an extra auxiliary verb "am", even though you have already used "can".

Comment: Ya that's true. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question

> Can I have that?

is correct and asks if it is (physically) possible for you the have something.  However, when asking, usually one is asking for permission and uses "may"

> Student: Can I have a drink of water?
>   Teacher: Yes, you can have a drink of water.  *(yes you are physically able to drink water)*
>
> Student: May I have a drink of water?
>   Teacher: No, you'll have to wait until break time to get some water.

Your second question is grammatically incorrect

> Can I am have that?

You may be mixing up the answer to your question with your question

> Q: Are you having dessert?
>   A: Yes, I **am** having dessert.